# R: install.packages() failed in Anaconda

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, install.packages

**1. Situation**: I bought a new laptop, and I installed anaconda

**2. Problem**

[image]

[also installing the dependencies 'cli', 'glue', 'lifecycle', 'pillar', 'rlang', 'tibble', 'tidyselect', 'vctrs'

Warning message:
"unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'를 열 수 없습니다"Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 'cli' 'glue' 'rlang' 'tibble' 'tidyselect' 'vctrs' 'dplyr'

These will not be installed

installing the source packages 'lifecycle', 'pillar'

Warning message in install.packages("dplyr"):
"installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("dplyr"):
"installation of package 'pillar' had non-zero exit status"]

I can't download any packages 'tidyverse', 'dplyr' and so on.

**3. I tried**

-repos='https://cran.r-project.org/'

-Add environment variables(Path) to the system

-delete anaconda and re-install

How can I resolve this? For your information, I am Korean, and Korean is not included in the Path.

Comment: How did you install anaconda? It seems to have installed R version 3.6 which is a very old version. There are often a lot of issues using R from anaconda when it comes to installing packages. Do you really need to install it that way? It's usually much easier to get things running if you install the official R release from https://www.r-project.org/

Comment: You may need to try another mirror `https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html` and R is at 4.3, do you HAVE to have 3.6?

Comment: This article will help getting a newer R, if it will pull up for you https://www.biostars.org/p/498049/